# What kind of Chinook helicopter/airplane hybrid is this?

Tags: wing, aircraft-identification, experimental-aircraft, ch-47

I had this question: [Could this helicopter's body be a flying wing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65142/could-this-helicopters-body-be-a-flying-wing) and this picture came up.

What kind of helicopter is this?
 What is the extra wing for?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's just Boeing trying to decide whether to build a plane or a chopper next.

Comment: @Mast The project was abandoned because the marketing department just couldn't do _anything_ with "plopper".

Comment: @DavidRicherby ... thanks now I have Arnie yelling "Get to the plopper!" stuck in my head.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It‘s a [BV-347 technology demonstrator](https://www.army.mil/article/194537/despite_failures_winged_chinook_experiment_led_to_army_aviation_fleet_improvements):

> In 1969, the Army and then-Boeing Vertol entered into a partnership to improve upon their cargo helicopter fleet, and thus the BV-347 was borne from a CH-47A Chinook that was provided by the Army as a technology demonstrator, according to retired CW5 Jim Kale, who now serves as a tour guide for the U.S. Army Aviation Museum.

Primary objectives as found in above article:

> The BV-347 was tested for more than two years and flew about 350 hours with the intention to meet five primary goals: improve flying qualities with external loads and instrument flight; im-prove stability, control and maneuverability in hover flight and forward flight with high gross weight; reduce rotor noise; reduce vibration stress; and create a modern cockpit environment with improved instrument and navigation displays.

The wing was intended to provide extra lift (works in forward flight only, of course), but apparently didn’t add net benefit:

> The wings were added as a means to improve lift, and although the addition served its purpose, the added weight canceled out any positive effects it provided [...].